# Relative path in HTML

Tags: html, relative-path, relative-url

I am creating a website on `localhost`. I want to make all of link resources in my website to relative path ( I mean only internal resources).

website is located in

```
http://localhost/mywebsite
```

I read this useful question [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls).

I found differences between `/images/example.png` and `images/example.png`

`<a href="/images/example.png"> Link To Image</a>`

Above relative path should return `ROOT_DOCUMENT/images/example.png` because of `/` at first of url. As `ROOT_DOCUMENT` is something like `/wamp/www/mywebsite`

But when I tested it, it only return `/wamp/www/images/example.png`

And I should add manually my website folder `/mywebsite/images/example.png` to relative path.

```
<a href="mywebsite/images/example.png"> Link To Image</a>
```

And it is not useful because of changing the name of mywebsite. So:

- Why does this problem occur?
- How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: This happens to me all the time when I use wampserver. Not an expert on how Apache/Web server works, but the idea is that the server operates over /var/www/ (its root) and your site is a subfolder within it. so if you put the / to make it absolute URL, then it takes the root that is /var/www/ (no subfolders) and you still need to add the folder where your web application is.

Comment: Put here virtualhost block of your apache config.

Comment: If you're starting your href's with `/` then that's not a relative path...that's site-root.

Answer (score 171):

You say your website is in `http://localhost/mywebsite`, and let's say that your image is inside a subfolder named `pictures/`:

**Absolute path**

If you use an **absolute path**, `/` would point to the **root** of the **site**, not the root of the document: `localhost` in your case. That's why you need to specify your document's folder in order to access the pictures folder:

```
"/mywebsite/pictures/picture.png"
```

And it would be the same as:

```
"http://localhost/mywebsite/pictures/picture.png"
```

**Relative path**

A **relative path** is always *relative* to the **root** of the **document**, so if your html is *at the same level* of the directory, you'd need to start the path directly with your picture's directory name:

```
"pictures/picture.png"
```

But there are other perks with relative paths:

**dot-slash (`./`)**

*Dot* (**`.`**) points to the same directory and the *slash* (**`/`**) *gives access* to it:

So this:

```
"pictures/picture.png"
```

Would be the same as this:

```
"./pictures/picture.png"
```

**Double-dot-slash (`../`)**

In this case, a double dot (**`..`**) points to the **upper directory** and likewise, the slash (**`/`**) gives you access to it. So if you wanted to access a picture that is on a directory one level above of the current directory your document is, your URL would look like this:

```
"../picture.png"
```

You can play around with them as much as you want, a little example would be this:

Let's say you're on directory **`A`**, and you want to access directory **`X`**.

```
- root
   |- a
      |- A
   |- b
   |- x
      |- X
```

Your URL would look either:

**Absolute path**

```
"/x/X/picture.png"
```

Or:

**Relative path**

```
"./../x/X/picture.png"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, So If I transfer my codes to a host then this line refers to root of document **"/pictures/picture.png"** & everything works true ?

Comment: Note that the behaviour of the relative path can be changed via the <base> tag (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

Answer (score 76):

The easiest way to solve this in pure HTML is to use the [`<base href="…">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element like so:

```
<base href="http://localhost/mywebsite/" />
```

Then all of the URLs in your HTML can just be this:

```
<a href="images/example.png">Link To Image</a>
```

Just change the `<base href="…">` to match your server. The rest of the HTML paths will just fall in line and will be appended to that.

Answer (score 4):

The relative pathing is based on the document level of the client side i.e. the URL level of the document as seen in the browser.

If the URL of your website is: `http://www.example.com/mywebsite/` then starting at the root level starts *above* the "mywebsite" folder path.