# Relative path in Script src and Link rel keeps resolving to root URL

Tags: javascript

I have a document located at `http://localhost:8081/develop`.

The `index.html`, located at `http://localhost:8081/develop/index.html` contains the following:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.min.css">
        <script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="./bower_components/moment/min/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
        <script src="./bower_components/elessar/dist/elessar.js"></script>
        <script src="./bower_components/EventSource/eventsource.js"></script>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

ALL of the files starts with a `./`, telling the browser that it should search them in the current directory, for example: `<script src="./bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>` should resolve into `http://localhost:8081/develop/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js`. That's obvious.

But it doesn't. Instead, they are being resolved into `http://localhost:8081/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js`, throwing tons of errors in the console.

[image]

The same thing will happen if instead of using `./` in the beginning of the files, I'd remove the first slash: `<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>` also resolves into `http://localhost:8081/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js`.

It feels like a very basic question but I really need that those files have relative paths and that those paths works as expected. So why aren't them?

Comment: Can you share what's the DOCTYPE or could you try changing the DOCTYPE? If I am not wrong then  `./` works with non-strict DOCTYPE.

Comment: It's has nothing to do with JS. Check your local server configuration...

Comment: @Shubh `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @BozidarSikanjic It has nothing to do with the server either. You can see in the screenshot attached that when I hover the mouse over the link, Chrome will show the URL it *thinks* it's the correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Reason can be tag `<base href="/">` in the head section.

Comment: This happened long ago but I still remember months later I figured out yes it was exactly for this reason.

Comment: You're a life saver.

Comment: Another reason I found that this happened was due to a load balancer (nginx) re-writing the URL to be at the root.  So all requests `https://host/some/path/afile.js` where mapped to `GET /afile.js` so if you have a load balancer, like apache, or nginx a mis-configured rewrite rule might be messing things up.