# $uibModal doesn't show my UI in my angular webpack project

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am calling below function on `ng-click` of a button.

```
vm.updateSourceAndVisibility = function(skus) {
  $log.info("In updateSourceAndVisibility");
  var modal = $uibModal.open({
    animation: true,
    template: require('./source-selection/source.selection.html'),
    controller: require('./source-selection/source.selection.controller.js'),
    controllerAs: 'sourceSelectCtrl',
    backdrop : 'static',
    size: 'md'
  });
};
```

When I click that button, a modal comes up having just

```
/src/app/pages/src/source-selection/source.selection.html
```

But **source.selection.html** has this HTML,

```
<form name="sourceSelectForm" novalidate>

  <!-- modal header -->
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ng-click="sourceSelectCtrl.close()"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Select Sources</h4>
  </div>

  <!-- modal body -->
  <div class="modal-body">
      <!-- Source information -->
      <div class="row">
        I want to put something here
      </div>
  </div>

  <!-- modal footer -->
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="sourceSelectCtrl.close()">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="sourceSelectCtrl.submit()">Select</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: not template change to templateUrl

Comment: When I change it to templateUrl, I get `404 Not Found http://localhost:8080/src/app/pages/src/source-selection/source.selection.html`

Comment: Template not found. Give correct path.

Comment: `./source-selection/source.selection.html` is the correct path. I am providing `templateUrl: require('./source-selection/source.selection.html')`

Comment: ../source-selection/source.selection.html 
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html

Comment: Actually the problem is something different I think, I have created an issue here as well https://github.com/STUkh/generator-angular-webpack-es6/issues/18