# How to set relative path in html

Tags: html, relative-path

I'm trying to change the path of my webpages from absolute to relative and im having trouble setting it.My server path is /username/project/webpages/homepage.html shouldn't the path be "../homepage.html"

Comment: It should depend of your system and stuffs, but in linux, to go up a folder, use only one dot, or the ~ sign to start from the home. When using two dots, the scope go on the top root folder structure. Try to train yourself with the ls command.
As well, in pure html, you can use the base element, which will define the root path of all files in the document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Relative path in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html)

Answer (score 2):

It depends where the page is being called from and please note that:

- A single dot `.` means the current folder
- Two dots `..` means the parent folder

In your example, you are using `..` which is incorrect if all your files are in the same folder i.e. webpages.