# Image not displayed online?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<img src="file:///C:/Users/magnu/Downloads/IMG_0342.JPG" alt="logo">
```

When I run the code in a browser locally on my PC, the image displays. But not when I view the site online. What am I doing wrong?

CSS:

```
img{
    width:210px;
    length:210px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    position:absolute;
    left:600px;
    top:300px;
  }
```

Comment: Update image's `src` attribute to server path.

Comment: You have to place the image file inside a path within your online site directory, then write the path to that place. Local files outside the scope of the site root path can't be accessed by it.

Comment: You should read a bit about file systems / paths, because it should be obvious to everyone working with web technologies that `file:///C:/Users/magnu/Downloads/IMG_0342.JPG` specifies a file on your local machine and therefore can not work on your online web server.

Comment: You might want to also check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls) and maybe [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html) too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```css
img{
    width:210px;
    height:210px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(270deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    top:100px;
  }
```

```html
<img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/beautiful_nature_landscape_05_hd_picture_166223.jpg" alt="logo">
```

Put your image on server. There are many options using which you can put your image online like [imgur](http://imgur.com/), [imgbb](https://imgbb.com/)

instead of giving `length` give `height` to your image.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set its location comppared with the location the html file for example if html file is located in c:/html/ and img is located in c:/  you  should to set img src as follow src="../img.jpg"   "../" to retun back by one folder

Answer (score -1):

IN the src you have to write the path without "file///":

```
<img src="C:/Users/magnu/Downloads/IMG_0342.JPG" alt="logo">
```

Comment: Do you really think this will work on his online webserver?

Comment: If the server is Windows based, yes it work.
If the server is Linux based, he has to modify the path to one similar to "/home/mysiye/media/randomimage.jpg".
All this only if the site's files are in the same server. 
If he doesn't host the site in the same server of the static files, he have to write a path like this: "https ://mysite.com/myfolderimages/myimages/".