# how to link php file available inside a folder

Tags: php, anchor

This is my Navbar code:

```
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="pages/about.php">about</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="pages/foreword.php">Foreword</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="pages/preface.php">Preface</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="pages/vission.php">Vision</a></li>
```

My pages are available inside the pages folder. When I press about on navbar, it navigates to:

```
localhost/pages/about.php
```

When I press foreword on navbar, it navigates to:

```
localhost/pages/pages/foreword.php
```

I am confused why it happens `localhost/pages/pages/`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are currently in the pages folder, then "pages/foreward.php" refers to "pages/pages/foreward.php".

Regardless of your location, you can force navigation to start at at the root of the website by prepending each of your links with a `/` like so:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="/pages/about.php">about</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="/pages/foreword.php">Foreword</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="/pages/preface.php">Preface</a></li>
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active" href="/pages/vission.php">Vision</a></li>
```

For more information about this, I suggest reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html) post on relative vs absolute paths.