# Styles doesn't work inside nested route

Tags: node.js, express

I have few routes in my website and I use the same layout with linked styles for all of my pages.

For example in route `/` or `/abc` or `/other` my layout and styles works good. However, if I load route `/other/abc` my layout still works but my styles don't load.

Here's some code:

My `layout`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Express MVC Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
   <ul class="menu">
     <li><a href="/">home</a></li>
     ...
     <li><a href="/other/abc">other/abc</a></li>
   </ul>

    {{{ body }}}

</body>
</html>
```

This is my `other` route `controllers`:

```
import express from 'express'

export default (app) => {
  const api = express.Router();

  api.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('client connected');
    res.render('other/main');
  });

  api.get('/abc', (req, res) => {
    res.render('other/abc');
  });

  return api
}
```

I use `handlebars` for `views`.

Comment: How do you serve your static file, `style.css` in this case, to client?

Comment: @Khang This way: `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is at how you specify the `style.css` link in your html, I think this will solve it:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```

If that does not work, look at this link [Relative path in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) (actually you should look at it anyway)