# static files not working in sub child routes in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, javascript-objects

I generated project structure using express-generator
In **app.js** I have following code :

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var minifyHTML = require('express-minify-html');
var minify = require('express-minify');



var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var aboutRouter = require('./routes/about');
var productsRouter = require('./routes/products');
var contactRouter = require('./routes/contact');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');


// Minifying HTML Code
app.use(minifyHTML({
    override:      true,
    exception_url: false,
    htmlMinifier: {
        removeComments:            true,
        collapseWhitespace:        true,
        collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes:     true,
        removeEmptyAttributes:     true,
        minifyJS:                  true
    }
}));

//Minifying JS Code
app.use(minify({
  cache: false,
  uglifyJsModule: null,
  errorHandler: null,
  jsMatch: /js/,
  cssMatch: /css/,
  jsonMatch: /json/,
  sassMatch: /scss/,
  lessMatch: /less/,
  stylusMatch: /stylus/,
  coffeeScriptMatch: /coffeescript/,
}));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/about-us', aboutRouter);
app.use('/products', productsRouter);
app.use('/contact-us', contactRouter);


// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

In productsRouter I have following code :

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/hospital-cubical-track-system', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('products/hospital-cubical-track-system', { title : 'Hospital Cubical Track System'});
});

router.get('/telescopic-iv-bag-hanger', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('products/telescopic-iv-bag-hanger', { title : 'Telescopic IV Bag Hanger'});
});

router.get('/wall-protection-system', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('products/wall-protection-system', { title : 'Wall Protection System'});
});

router.get('/hospital-blinds', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('products/hospital-blinds', { title : 'Hospital Blinds'});
});

router.get('/nurse-call-system', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('products/nurse-call-system', { title : 'Nurse Call System'});
});

router.get('/hospital-linen', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('products/hospital-linen', { title : 'Hospital Linen'});
});


module.exports = router;
```

Now on sub routes like "products/hospital-cubical-track-system", Static css files of design are not loading while on "/, /about, /contact" loading css js static files fine.
kindly help me

Comment: You can try `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../public')));`

Comment: Thank you pradeep to reply, but your method will not work. `../public` would create problem in root routers like /about

Comment: Using absolute path over relative path should solve this problem. `app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` Ref: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html

Comment: you are right, but it is not serving static files on child routes of a route

Comment: Can you please give an example of a static file's path that is not loading?

Comment: Thanks joseps for replying. CSS, JS, imaages files path not loading.  When I look at source code, chiled routs actually loading localhost/products/css/style.css instead of localhost/css/style.css. This is happening only child of product router. but working fine with other main routers

Comment: How do you reference the static files in your HBS templates? It sounds like you might be using some relative paths which only resolve correctly when you're "zero or one level deep", e.g., in "/", "/about", or "/contact".

Comment: in hbs layout file, i am using path like 'css/style.css', 'js/main.js'

Comment: Are you using relative references for the asset files? That seems like what's wrong. So instead of using `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />` you should use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />` (notice the beginning `/` indicating to use the root of your website. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028813/1148564) for more info.

Comment: Thanks joseph serido. You helped me a lot and gave solution fast. It worked

Comment: @PiyushGupta you're welcome. I added an answer so others can benefit as well. Feel free to accept it if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you @joseph serido. I have posted another question, could you please analyse that ? I want to use localhost smtp with nodemailer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the comments it sounds like you are you using relative references for the asset files in your html pages when you should use absolute references.

So instead of using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
```

You should use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css" />
```

Notice the beginning `/` indicating to use the root of your website. See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028813/1148564) for more info.

Comment: Thank you so much! you are a lifesaver.