# Linking Internal Files in HTML

Tags: jquery, html, file, filepath, relative-path

I am trying to link internal files in my HTML code, but for some reason am unable to. I used terminal to get the file path and double checked it was right but am missing something. In the code below the link to index works but not to Marios Page, if someone could guide me to what I'm doing wrong it would be much appreciated.

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Laura</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Laura's Page</h1>
<p>Hello I am the Laura.html file</p>
<a href="/Users/bobgohary/Desktop/Linking/Index.html">Click me to go to back to Index :() </a>
<a href="/Users/bobgohary/Desktop/Linking/Europe/Italy/Tuscany/Mario.html">Click me to go to back to Mario's Page </a>



</body>
```

Comment: you shouldn't use an absolute directory path. that won't work on a web server.

Comment: What would you recommend?  Its been a while since i did HTML and i'm having trouble. Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your paths are absolute, but HTML doesn't use absolute file paths. Use a relative path instead.

So let's say for example your `index.html` file is in the path

```
/Users/bobgohary/Desktop/index.html
```

And you have another file here:

```
/Users/bobgohary/Desktop/Linking/Europe/Italy/Tuscany/Mario.html
```

You need to figure out how to get to `Mario.html` ***from*** `index.html`, and here's the solution:

```
<a href="/Linking/Europe/Italy/Tuscany/Mario.html">
```

This is the way you should link files in HTML.

Comment: No worries @fijilemon12. Is mine the accepted answer?