# i wanted to link the html and css files. but does not work

Tags: html

```
<html>

<head>

<title> HELLO </title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="back.css"/>

</head>

<body>

<h1> WELCOME TO THE NEW WORLD </h1>

<p>  This is the world of Oppurtunities </p>

</body>

</html>
```

the css file is below.

```
body{
    background-color: darkslategrey;
    color: azure;
     }

h1{
    color: coral;
     }
```

Comment: show us the files tree of the project also, please

Comment: Is back.css in the same folder as your html file? Also, remove the closing slash on your link element.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It works fine when I copy/paste your data. Probably you just have a typo in the URL.

Comment: What do you mean this code, please write some about this code!.

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console? Also when you say "does not work" do you refer to the stylesheet not loading or the style not being applied correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You question is pretty vague but your path to the CSS is probably off.

Without more info on your dev environment this is my best suggestion.

Change your CSS link to...

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../back.css"/>` Notice the ./back.css

This may not be the correct path to the file but your issue lies in your [relative path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028813/3204142).  It all depends on your file structure.

**Basic Examples**

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/back.css"/>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="../back.css"/>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="/someFolder/back.css"/>`

Comment: `./back.css` and `back.css` resolve to exactly the same URL. This cannot make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps putting the css file into a folder might work out.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="styles/back.css"/>
```

That usually does the trick, let us know ;)!