# Routes gets undefined after refresh in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

App.jsx

```
<Router history={history}>
      <>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />          
          <Route path="/test/:id" exact component={TestPage} /> 
          <Route component={NotFound} />         
        </Switch>
      </>
</Router>
```

HomePage.jsx inside render()

```
<Link to="/test/1" >Test link</Link>
```

When I click on the link the page successfully redirects me on http://localhost:8080/test/1 and i can see the page but If I click refresh the page is gone and I can only see the blank screen, also If I want to access it from outside i.e. If I directly type the same url on browser I cannot see the page, It's blank. How to manage it on refresh and access it from outside?

Message on console I get on refresh

[image: error]

Comment: how are you loading that main.js file?

Comment: Hello @tudor.gergely Inside source I can see <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" async></script></body>

Comment: use src="/main.js"

Comment: Hello @ssk I don't know exactly where to edit the "main.js" to "/main.js" I can see         {
  "name": "minimal-webpack-react",
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "description": "Boilerplate for react and webpack",
  "main": "index.js",                                                                                                                        }                                                                                                                                                 Should I edit it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the app cannot load your main.js script from you second url (it tries to load it from /test/main.js). You need to use an absolute path to load from `/` instead of `/test`

Replace you script tag with this one (loading it from /main.js):
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js">`

You can refer to this answer for a more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24028813/3350692

Comment: Hello @tudor.gergely, but I have inspected the source of page when it's working there also I can see "main.js" and it's working totally fine

Comment: yes, but when you enter /test (or refresh on /test) it will try and load your script from that url because you used a relative path. Use absolute paths for scripts (like I've shown you in the answer) and you will not have this problem.

Comment: Ok, I will edit that but where can I find that main.js path, my webpack look something like this  `output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    path: commonPaths.outputPath,
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
  }` Is this the place to edit ? I exactly don't know where to find the path for main.js

Comment: where is your index.html file?

Comment: @Adarsh edit your main html file, where you have <body> tag defined. change there `<body> <div id="app"></div> <script type="text/javascript" src="/main.js" async></script></body>`

Comment: my template.html(index.html) is inside /src/template.html and inside that i can only see `   <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>` maybe its dynamically creating the script

Comment: I'm using this boiler plate https://github.com/HashemKhalifa/webpack-react-boilerplate

Comment: @Adarsh Try changing webpack.common.js output.publicPath to '/'. You can also try to edit template.html inside src and add `<base href="/">` in the <head>.