# I keep getting an "unable to open file... file not found" message on vs code, despite my files being in the same workspace

Tags: html, visual-studio

Whenever I try to link an HTML file, I keep getting the "file not found" message, although all of my files are in the same workspace. Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

How about you try with: `<li><a href="needed.html"> Needed Grade</a></li>`. 
NOTICE there is no spacing  between `href` and `="needed.html"`

If that still doesn't work try with `<li><a href="/needed.html"> Needed Grade</a></li>`.

It may sound absurd, but first of all be sure you didn't commit any typo errors in your code. Also, it is most likely the URL with which you are trying to link such file doesn't have the right structure. For example: you might be mistakingly looking for a path that doesn't exists. Or confusing a relative path with an absolute one.

Please take a look at the first answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html), or at [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/html-file-paths/), and let me know if I was of any help (or even if I did not understood your issue at all).

Best regards!

Comment: I don't exactly follow the solution. How would I change this code

Comment: <li><a href = "needed.html"> Needed Grade</a></li>