# selenium error WebDriverException: unknown error: no chrome binary in asp core

Tags: selenium

I am using selenium in asp core 3.1,
in local it's working,
but in server windows 2012 there's an error:

> WebDriverException: unknown error: no chrome binary

I set binary and driver:

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";            
_driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath), chromeOptions);
```

but not work

Answer (score 0):

In local this works, since it is an absolute path, relating to your system.

```
chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
```

This of-course will not work on the server, as this would fail as it's not the same path. You would ideally want to use a relative path style.

Comment: how do i relative path style?

Comment: This must simply be a path issue, and nothing else. Can you try this `chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe"; `. And also make sure that it's the correct binary 
`

Comment: Does `chrome.exe` actually exist in that path you've given? Is it not`Chrome.exe` or `ChromeDriver.exe`? For configuring relative path see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html)

Comment: yes its exist, this is in local work, but not it work  in server

Comment: this path in server : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"