# HTML href question - What does ..\ do in this statement?

Tags: html

HTML href question  - What does ..\ do in this statement?
What happens when I click on Michael?

```
<a href="..\canyonoakscc_golf_m23/Member_mgs?user=8xxx&name=Michael&message=" alt="Michael">Michael</a>
```

Comment: "What happens when I click on Michael?" Well, you don't need to ask us -- just click it :).

Comment: What happens when you click the link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative path in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html)

Comment: I find this a bit weird, because the slash is in fact a backslash… does a backslash also represent a path separator?

Answer (score 1):

This path is 'relative' to the current directory. Specifically, `..` references the parent directory. This is convention in both Windows and (most) Linux filesystems.

The link is referencing the parent directory of the one that the current page was sourced from.

More information - https://superuser.com/q/153165