# How to change the name of public_path in my laravel app (which had been deployed by cpanel)?

Tags: laravel, web, path, cpanel

I have public_path in my app, /home/user/public_html but I wanna change it into my app domain, [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com), so when I upload files, those files will be accessed by URL: [www.mydomain.com/File/Uploaded_Photo.jpg](http://www.mydomain.com/File/Uploaded_Photo.jpg) instead of /home/user/public_html/File/Uploaded_Photo.jpg

Could anyone help and teach me? Thanks before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative path in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html)

Comment: Just changing the .env is enough. To access the images I recommend using the asset() function.

Comment: Thanks @HamzaAbdaoui but, that's different case  it doesn't answer for what i need

Comment: @SantiagoCurvello I don't think it's the suitable solution, because the .env file is a setting of something else. Thanks for your suggestion (:

Answer (score 0):

run php artisan cache:clear and run the command php artisan storage:link this will create storage symlink inside public/asset/storage and solve your issue