# About adding a link to external file (another directory located) in existing html document through <a> tag

Tags: html, hyperlink, frontend

In the tutorials that I follow, they have shown to use the `anchor` tag for creating hyperlinks to other websites or other files in the local host but in the same directory, with respect to the current HTML file I am creating.

However, I want to add a `hyperlink` to a file in another directory from my webpage using the `anchor` tag. I'm currently creating my HTML file in `Local disk D` and my target file is in `Local disk C`.

Is it possible to do so?

Here is my code for the anchor tag:

```html
<a href="C:/Users/LENOVO/Received/Videos/Movies/www.toadypk.stream - Geetha Govindam (2018) Telugu True HDRip x264 MP3 700MB.mkv.mp4">
   Movie
</a>
```

Comment: Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: It's a good opportunity to learn the basics between relative and absolute paths. In this thread you will find more information: [Relative path in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html) - As wazz said, feel free to show some code examples from you.