# Image not displayed in vs code

Tags: html, css, image, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I use VS Code, and Live Server extension, I am trying to put an image with the `<img>` tag, the image was in the same folder and named **coin.png**, I tried to type `<img src="coin.png>"` but this is what I get in the browser [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FJt6.png), I tried to see the browser's console and I got this message `coin.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`, the weird thing is that it works with any other IDE, why does that happen and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use relative path or absolute path from your html file to your image file like this

```
<img src="./coin.png" />
```

If your image file is in the same place with your html file
Or

```
<img src="[path to your image file]/coin.png" />
```

Comment: , i have tried this already, i still get the same problem, try it your self with live server please and tell me if it works or the problem if from me

Comment: you can find solution in this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html)

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in addition to Live Server extension, [issue 2982 "inline HTML results"](https://github.com/julia-vscode/julia-vscode/issues/2982) is gaining traction now (May 2023) that there is progress on [`xtermjs/xterm.js` issues 614](https://github.com/xtermjs/xterm.js/issues/614).

You can see a concrete example with application With [VSCode PR 182442](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/182442) (from [issue 182443](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/182443)) which integrates [`jerch/xterm-addon-image`](https://github.com/jerch/xterm-addon-image): it comes with support for both sixel and iTerm's inline image protocol (png, jpeg, gif [initial frame]).

That means you can also see pictures directly from a VSCode terminal:

[image: picture in terminal]

This is available with VSCode 1.79 May 2023 (or [VSCode insiders today](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)).
This is finalized with VSCode 1.80 (June 2023): [PR 184449](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/184449/files).

> ### `terminal.integrated.enableImages`
>
> Enables image support in the terminal.
> Both sixel and iTerm's inline image protocol are supported on Linux and macOS, Windows support will light up automatically when ConPTY passes through the sequences.
> Images will currently not be restored between window reloads/reconnects.