# Base layout does not load when accepting dynamic url

Tags: javascript, python, web, web.py

I am using web.py for a web project. I have the following url structure

```py
urls = (
    '/', 'Home',
    '/register','Register',
    '/postregistration', 'PostRegistration',
    '/login', 'Login',
    '/check-login', 'CheckLogin',
    '/logout', 'Logout',
    '/post-activity', 'PostActivity',
    '/profile/(.*)/info', 'userInfo',
    '/profile/(.*)', 'Profile',
    '/abcd', 'abcd'
    )
```

Everything works fine but when i try to visit pages which have dynamic link like "/profile/anything" my web page loads without the css & js added in base layout. On inspecting and checking sources i noticed that on these urls my all css & js file have html content inside them.

[image]

Comment: In the CSS links replace the backslashes with forward slashes and add an extra one at the beginning.

Comment: yeah that was the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to chance the code seen within the static files, is the HTML you're serving from the *any url* endpoint.

The `static/` URL is resolving through your anything URL, because they don't start with an absolute path. Here's an example of a CSS Link, I can see in the screenshot:

`<link href='static\css\profile.css'>` (relative from the current path)

should look more like:

`<link href='/static/css/profile.css'>` (absolute from the server root)

The same applies for your JS. More about relative pathing can be perused here: [Relative path in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html)