# iframe does not appear in .cshtml

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have CHART.html in my local folder, I want to display it in other .html page

I try this in Index.cshtml (I create ASP.NET MVC project):

```
<iframe src="C:\Users\Tomat\Documents\Projects\My_own_projects\Trash\CHART.html" 
        width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

but it creates blank iframe with given width and height

What did I do wrong?

In pure .html file it works fine, my CHART.html  is displayed inside another.

**EDIT**

Use of relative path works for me

`<iframe src="../../CHART.html" </iframe>`

*Thanks a lot to* @computercarguy and @ToxicFlame427

Comment: Hit F12, see your browser's errors in the console.

Comment: It's probably because you are using an absolute reference to the file on your computer instead of a relative path on your site. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24028561/relative-path-in-html

Comment: Use a relative path, not an absolute one